# Update WMS params in OL3 + React

Tags: openlayers, wms, react

I have an OL3 map with a WMS layer generated in a React component. I'm trying to update the parameters of the `ol.source.ImageWMS()` dynamically, using React props to set `CQL_FILTER` and `STYLES` parameters.

Here's a basic example :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ol from "openlayers";

export default class Map extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {

        let wms = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                url: 'http://url/wms',
                params: {
                    LAYERS: 'layer',
                }
            })

        let layer = new ol.layer.Image({source: wms})
        let map = new ol.Map({
            target: this.refs.map,
            layers: [layer],
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="map" ref="map"></div>
        )
    }
}
```

Now let's say my app state feeds the component with an `id` and a `style`. In what `React` lifecycle hook and with what `Openlayers` method can we update WMS parameters?

- I first failed using for ex: `CQL_FILTER = 'attribute={this.props.id}'`, or `STYLES = '{this.props.style}`
- I also failed putting the logic into a function and calling it like this: `CQL_FILTER = setCQL.bind(this)`
- I then discovered there was a dedicated OL3 method called `updateParams()`.
  My failed implementation of that method was to call it at the end of the `componentDidMount()` hook,

like so :

```
let wmsStyle = !this.props.style ? '' : 'style1'
let cqlFilter = !this.props.id ? '' : 'attribute=id1'

wms.updateParams({
    CQL_FILTER: cqlFilter,
    STYLES: wmsStyle,
})
```

This doesn't even work with static parameters. I'm running out of ideas and I'm not even sure if it is a React or an OpenLayers issue. Anyone?

Comment: It would help if you have some some mini demo on code sandbox or something similar to it  and use debug ol .